# on click of UITableViewCell, UIWebView not able to Load webPage

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiwebview

i am making an iPad application,

i want to load 2 webPage on single UIWebView one after another,

1st webpage should come when i load my application,and 2nd webpage should come on click of cell of tableView,

so,inside my didLoad method i am writing this (1st webpage),

```
   NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";

      //Create a URL object.
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

     //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
   [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

it works fine..

but on the same page on same webview on click of cell of tableView i want to load another page,(2nd webpage)
 i written code for loading 2nd webPage,

here is the code snippet for 2nd webPage,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 DatabasesViewController *nextController=[[DatabasesViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DatabasesViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
        [nextController changeProductText:[a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [nextController changeProductText1:[b objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [nextController changeProductText2:[d objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

}
```

when i selects a cell inside tableView,
it navigates to new view, i don't want to navigate, i want to stay on same page what changes should i do in above function ?

in above function changeProductText,changeProductText1,changeProductText2, are three IBAction and a,b,d are my array names.

```
- (IBAction) changeProductText:(NSString *)str{

    l1=@"http://ipad.appel.com/indexcharts.aspx?id=";
    l2=str;

    NSString *str1 = [l1 stringByAppendingString:l2];

    NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:str1];
    NSURLRequest *req2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [webView loadRequest:req2];
}
```

when i click on cell of tableView webView is not displaying,

do i need to clear webpage or reload webpage something like that ?

**Help Me Guys, Thanx in Advance !!**

Comment: Do you understand the following lines ?
"DatabasesViewController *nextController= ..."
"[self.navigationController pushViewController..."

the second is responsible for navigating to a new view. if you don't want it, don't write it.

if webview is a controller variable, you can try to use 
"self changeProductText:"
instead of "nextController changeProductText:" i can not consider that as an answer if you don't actually understand it and need more details, so please let others know what you think.

Comment: dude.. you rock it's working fine... but i am not able to see webpage, any solution for that ?

Comment: i want to load a webpage on click of cell of tableView, but unable to load webPage..  :(

Comment: glad it helped. do you see google.com or an empty page ? you could set the view controller to be a webview delegate, there's a method called when error occurs: "- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
" you can use it to nslog the errors and see what exactly failed. and to check that webpage has started an update you can use the delegate method "- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
" see more at http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: NSString *str1 = [l1 stringByAppendingString:l2];
    NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:str1];
    NSURLRequest *req2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [webView loadRequest:req2];

Comment: just try to nslog str1 before making it a url, then copy it and try to open with Safari or any other internet browser. I tried a few parameters and got a blank screen. from a really fast review of a page source i would say there's a problem with javascript. please test your url's and let us know your results.

Comment: i tried my log of str1 b4 and after making url, that both working, i also tried my url in safari it also working, but not showing in my simulator..

Comment: i tried google.com, on click of cell of tableView it's working, but when i load my url,it doesn't work.. why this ? i am making url like this, NSString *l1=@"ipad.idealake.com/indexcharts.aspx?id=";; NSString *l2=str; str is my parameter,on click of cell i will get value of cell, and i will append to url, when i log my str1, it is correct but when pass my url to webView it doesn't load webPage... see my code above in comment

Comment: is it possible that you share a link you are trying to load ?

Comment: l1=@"http://ipad.idealake.com/indexcharts.aspx?id="; and l2=str; str is parameter. str will be either CNX 100 or CNX MIDCAP or CNX SMALLCAP depends on user, after  i am appending l1 and l2,  NSString *str1 = [l1 stringByAppendingString:l2]; and passing str1 to webView

Comment: try this:     NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ipad.idealake.com/indexcharts.aspx?id=%@", str];    
    url = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];

please let us know if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6542/discussion-between-user792677-and-krunal-lathia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You can use the UISplitViewController for this issue.

EDIT : Now check out the code like this..

```
   -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectedRowAtIndexPath:
                (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                 NSString *urlString = [siteAddress objectAtIndex : indexPath.row];
                 detailViewController.webView.scalesPageToFit= yes;
                 NSUrl *url = [NSUrlRequest requestWithURL : url];
                 [detailViewController.webView loadRequest : request];
            }
```

Comment: thanx it works.. now, i want to load a webpage on click of cell of tableView, but unable to load webPage.. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
```

This navigates you away from the page. It pushes a new view onto the navigation stack. Get rid of it if you don't want to do that.What is this a splitView?